# How to contain title between 2 lines

Tags: titles

I'm looking for the effect in the following image. Ive done it by putting 2 images of lines above and beneath the title but that is quite lame, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something without the usual `\maketitle` approach, using a `\tcolorbox`, all wrapped up in a command.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}




\newcommand{\MyTitle}[4][]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,arc=0mm,auto outer arc,boxrule=0pt,toprule=3pt,bottomrule=3pt,colframe=black,colback=white,top=1cm,bottom=1cm,#1]
\begin{flushright}%
\begin{tabular}{r}
#2 \tabularnewline%
\tabularnewline  %
#3 \tabularnewline
\tabularnewline %
#4 \tabularnewline%
\tabularnewline %
\end{tabular} 
\end{flushright}%
\end{tcolorbox}%
\clearpage%
}%


\begin{document}


\MyTitle{\Large \textbf{Dies ist der Titel der Dissertation}}{\large \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{und hier eventuell ein Untertitel}}}{\large\textbf{\textcolor{darkgray}{Otto Normalverbraucher}}}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for this answer Christian, I apologize for not providing a MWE.